# Nunit Testing issue with Connection string

Tags: c#, nunit, app-config

I'm trying to use Nunit in my application, and this error `TestCalculCommission.calculcomTest._AvecValeur179_Retourne6:
System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'EntitiesMAE' could be found in the application config file.` :
[image]

In my Project Config I have added `App.config` in The configuration fileName and I reloaded my project but still same error . How to fix it please

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632297/how-do-i-configure-my-settings-file-to-work-with-unit-tests?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318423/access-app-config-settings-from-class-library-called-through-unit-test-project?rq=1 should help

Comment: Sorry but this dosn't sloved my problem

Comment: I got this error `I got .net Framework not available`